# Make button send data to database (blank page works on reload?)

Tags: php, laravel

I have a CRUD system which allows users to create, edit and delete their own social groups. These groups are then shown on a public page and other users can view and join the social groups.

The `create_group` system works perfectly and groups display on a public page. Info is stored in database table `groups`.

I want users to be able to click a 'Join Group' button and for the `group_title` to be recorded in the database.

The idea being that they can then view the groups they joined later from their dashboard.

I'm not 100% sure on how to go about this as I'm new to coding. My instincts were to create another CRUD system called Join, but this is possible overkill?

I've taken these steps:

1. Created database table called 'Joins'
2. Created a CRUD system the same as the 'Create Group' CRUD. *I guess I just won't use the edit or create features of this CRUD.*
3. I placed this button on the public group viewable page:

```html
<form method="post" action="{{ route('join.store') }}">
    <input type="submit" name="{{ $group->group_title }}" value="Join Group" class="btn btn-success" />
</form>
```

Something very strange happens when clicking the button, it takes me to the correct page `http://version2.test/join` but the page is blank, showing a

> Page Expired

error. However, if I refresh the page, or even copy the URL to a new page, it will display correctly!?

Also, when viewing `http://version2.test/join`, I do not see the group title displaying.

**UPDATE #1** - I then added @csrf to the button like so:

```html
<form method="post" action="/test">
    @csrf
    <input type="hidden" name="group_title" value="{{ $group->group_title }}">
    <input type="submit" value="Join Group" class="btn btn-success" />
</form>
```

At first, I thought this fixed the 'Page Expired' error, but later realized that it didn't. The 'Join Group' button still directs to `http://version2.test/join` but the page is showing a 'Page Expired' error. However, if I refresh the page, or even copy the URL to a new page, it will display correctly.

`JoinController.php`

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Join;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

// All join pages require login except 'show'
class JoinController extends Controller
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth', ['except' => 'show']);
    }

    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $join = Join::all();

        return view('join/index', compact('join'));
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        return view('join.create');
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'group_title' => 'required',
            // 'group_description' => 'required',
            // 'group_date' => 'required',
            // 'group_time' => 'required',
        ]);

        $join = new Join([
            'group_title' => $request->get('group_title'),
            // 'group_description' => $request->get('group_description'),
            // 'group_date' => $request->get('group_date'),
            // 'group_time' => $request->get('group_time'),
        ]);
        $join->save();
        return redirect('/join')->with('success', 'Group joined!!');
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
        $join = Join::find($id);
        return view('join.show', compact('join'));
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit($id)
    {
        $join = Join::find($id);
        return view('join.edit', compact('join'));
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'group_title' => 'required',
            // 'group_description' => 'required',
            // 'group_date' => 'required',
            // 'group_time' => 'required',
        ]);

        $join = Join::find($id);
        $join->group_title =  $request->get('group_title');
        // $group->group_description = $request->get('group_description');
        // $group->group_date = $request->get('group_date');
        // $group->group_time = $request->get('group_time');
        $join->save();
        return redirect('/join')->with('success', 'Group joined!');
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        $join = Join::find($id);
        $join->delete();

        return redirect('/join')->with('success', 'Unjoined!');
    }
}
```

Join.php

```php
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Join extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'group_title',
        // 'group_description',
        // 'group_date',
        // 'group_time',
    ];
}
```

`join/index.blade.php`

```html
<tbody>
    @foreach($join as $join)
    <tr>
        <td>
            <a href="{{ route('group_join.show',$group->id)}}">{{$group->group_title}}</a>
        </td>
        <td>
            <a href="{{ route('group_join.edit', $group->id)}}" class="btn btn-sm btn-warning">Edit</a>
        </td>
        <td>
            <form action="{{ route('group_join.destroy', $group->id)}}" method="post">
                @csrf
                @method('DELETE')
                <button class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" type="submit">Delete</button>
            </form>
        </td>
    </tr>
    @endforeach
</tbody>
```

`routes/web.php`

```php
Route::resource('join', 'JoinController');
```

Answer (score 0):

If that's a form, you could check if changing

```
'group_title' => $request->get('group_title')
```

into

```
'group_title' => $request->input('group_title')
```

in your `store` method would do the trick.

Since this field is required and you're not getting an error, the data passes to your action. Check if that works.

[source](https://laraveldaily.com/differences-request-get-vs-request-input-vs-helper-vs-get_data/)

Comment: This didn't work. I still was lead to a dead page which works on refresh and data still not going to database.